# I'm getting this 'PHP Deprecated' issue

Tags: errors, debug

> PHP Deprecated: Hook contextual_help is deprecated since version 3.3.0! Use get_current_screen()->add_help_tab(), get_current_screen()->remove_help_tab() instead. in /container/application/public/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6031

I'm getting this issue and seems like it is my active theme that's causing it. Theme is **Enfold**, what can I possible do to resolve this?

Comment: Ask on the enfold support forum.  From my experience, they respond quickly.

Comment: 3.3.0 was December 2011, and Themeforest says Enfold was first released in 2013. So unless they've been ignoring the warning themselves since the very start I'd guess it's not them. I'd try grepping all of your files for 'contextual_help' too to see where it actually comes up: is it Enfold, or a child theme if you have one, or a plugin?